# How to set transactional email api key for external app in drupal like mandrill

Tags: emails

Like mandril,I have app for routing system transactional mails through that.I got create account in that app and getting api key for my drupal site,But i dont know how to process it (where to add that api key to configure it)on drupal to send mail.please clarify.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're using the [Mandrill module](https://www.drupal.org/project/mandrill), the API key can be configured at this path:

**/admin/config/services/mandrill**

Comment: so need to create module like mandrill,right?

Answer (score 0):

Send your transactional emails from Drupal using [Pepipost](http://www.pepipost.com/), you may use the SMTP Authentication Support module or the Swift Mailer module depending on your needs.

Ref: http://support.pepipost.com/knowledge_base/topics/drupal